# Shopware 6 determine version

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have a shopware installation with the dev template. There is no .git folder so I don´t know which Shopware version or commit was/is used. In the composer.json I have something like this: "shopware/platform": "6.4.x@dev" So I know it was 6.4.x But no minor version or which commit.

My plan is to migrate this to the production template but I want to do a diff (with the original version) and migrate some things into plugins (which where changed in the platform).

Is there an other way to determine the shopware version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the installed version either in the composer.lock by searching e.g. shopware/administration

"name": "shopware/administration",
"version": "6.4.12.0",

or you can login into the admin interface and in the upper left corner you also find the version.

[image]

Or if you don't have a composer installation, the only way to find out will be to compare the existing migration files and other recently changing files and folders unfortunatelly.

https://github.com/shopware/platform/tree/trunk/src/Core/Migration

Comment: composer.json I have "shopware/administration": "self.version", and in the backend I have v6.4.99 Stable Version 99999.9999999

Comment: Unfortunately the entry for `shopware/core` in the composer.json isn't really of use either: `"shopware/core": "*"`

Comment: not the composer.json, you need the composer.lock there you find all installed versions, this file should be in the same location like your composer.json, if it is an shopware setup made via composer

Answer (score 1):

You can pin the Shopware version to a specific release in the `composer.json` e.g. by setting it to `"shopware/platform": "6.4.13.0"`. You could then run `composer install` again but there might be differences in the database structure, changed administration builds and so on. So once you pin the version it might be best to run `./psh.phar install` which will do all of that (including the `composer install` step). You can find all available versions over at [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/shopware/platform).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Probably should've been specified in the question, but the reason we wanted to know the initial version of our installation was that we planned on updating the shopware core which we (unfortunately) monkey patched a bit. So we had to determine the installed version to get an accurate git diff.